# WPF combobox. Как прибандить SelectedItem при динамическом додавлении ComboboxItem

Tags: wpf, combobox

Все привет. У меня возникла проблема. При редактировании заявки я додаю участников заявки с выбраным документом. Естественно додаю динамически, полаченные з БД. Додаю в контейнер Grid. И ComboBox додаю динамически, естественно. Вопрос: как для каждого ComboBox задать свой SelectedItem?
Вот мой тип доданых документов

```
public class OrderMember : BindableBase
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<ClientDocument> Documents { get; set; }

    private ClientDocument _selectedDocument;
    public ClientDocument SelectedDocument
    {
        get { return _selectedDocument; }
        set
        {
            _selectedDocument = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот я додаю список елементов

```
            int rowNum = 1;
            foreach (var m in OrderMembers)
            {
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                grOrderMembers.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

                TextBlock tbID = new TextBlock();
                tbID.Text = m.ID.ToString();
                Grid.SetColumn(tbID, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(tbID, rowNum);
                grOrderMembers.Children.Add(tbID);

                TextBlock tbFullName = new TextBlock();
                tbFullName.Text = m.Name;
                Grid.SetColumn(tbFullName, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(tbFullName, rowNum);
                grOrderMembers.Children.Add(tbFullName);

                ComboBox cbDocuments = new ComboBox();
                cbDocuments.ItemsSource = m.Documents;
                var selectedDoc = new Binding("SelectedDocument");

                cbDocuments.SelectedItem = selectedDoc;
                Grid.SetColumn(cbDocuments, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(cbDocuments, rowNum);
                cbDocuments.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
                grOrderMembers.Children.Add(cbDocuments);

                rowNum++;
            }
```

Comment: Вы сами себе придумали костыли всей этой "динамикой". Научитесь использовать XAML и правильные привязки!

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что хотите. Могу предложить такой вариант разместите все ваши comboboxы и управляйте visibility

Comment: У меня такая задача. Если не знаете сами, то зачем писать